# Make a div editable and capture the value in a form as if it was a textarea

Tags: reactjs

I'm just challenging my new skills in react and have some issues.
I'm trying to make a div editable to replace the textarea in my form. I face issues  when trying to capture the data typed in.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function CreateNotes(params) {

    const [note, setNote] = useState({
        title: "",
        content: ""
    });

    function handleChange(event) {

        const {name, value} = event.target;

        setNote(prevValue => {
            return ({
                ...prevValue,
                [name]: value
            })
        })
    }

    return <div>
        <form action="">
            <input 
            name="title"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Titre"
            value={note.title}
            onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <div
            onTextArea="true"
            name="content"
            contentEditable="true"
            ariaMultiline="true"
            ariaLabel="Take a note"
            value={note.content}
            onClick={handleChange}
            ></div>
        </form>
    </div>
}


export default CreateNotes;
```

The div turns to be undefined even when something is typed.

Comment: ... why? What's wrong with using the form element that was designed to do that thing you're trying to do?

Comment: Hi Mike, i want everything to be shown while typing without the need of scrolling, which happen for long text with textarea

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the pre-built plugin [react-contenteditable](https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable).  I found myself trying to do exactly what you were doing, and this plugin executes it very well.  You can study the source code if you want to understand it for learning's sake.